# Is $model->load() in Yii2 is safe?

Tags: php, yii2

Is it safe to load data into the model via load() method?
In $model there is only name and email properties, that have only "string" validator.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->save()){

}
```

When i do something like shown above, is it safe against sql injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is! (sorry I couldn't resist the joke).

Actually the model is an abstraction from the database, so it does not care about what DB your are using and/or what problems could occur. Usually, in Yii2 most of the DB operations occur via ActiveRecord, that uses [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) 
 that prevent SQL injection atacks.

If you won't be using ActiveRecord though, I recommend you to read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html#avoiding-sql-injections).

Comment: What exactly "string" validator does? How it prevents sql injections?

Comment: It checks that the value is a string, and fulfills the additional restrictions you specified (if any). Protection against SQL injections come from ActiveRecord internal PDO statements, check my updated answer